# Using the fl.quit() in my JSFL script crashed Animate 2017.5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, jsfl

I am running Flash on a Desktop mode version of Windows Server 2012 for automated builds. In my JSFL file, I am publishing files Canvas FLA files and then closing the IDE with fl.quit(false); in my code. It runs fine on my Windows 10 machine but crashes on the Windows Server 2012 machine. This is causing issues as the code is needing be run by an ant script for users who cannot see this screen and can't hit the close program button to dismiss the error and finish the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that Windows Server 2012 when running under desktop mode, does not work well with Animate CC and as far as I can tell there is no fix for this issue.